# Crash when select file after

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, file-manager

App getting crashed while selecting file from `file manager`.
My Application `Screen orientation="Landscape"` and file manager open in "**portrait**" after a select file getting crash.

Any idea why?

> Error:" java.lang.IllegalStateException: txtTime must not be null
>           at com.mathsolver.app.fragments.FragMain$setTimerForChangeProblem$1.run(FragMain.kt:77)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) ""

Comment: Post your stack trace

Comment: App Orientation: Landscape

Step 1: Open file chooser

step 2: choose file 
(File manager open in "Portrait" mode)

after select getting crash

Comment: @BipinBharti post the logs without it no one can understand properly what was the error.

Comment: What is crash report?

Comment: @Piyush Above Error Report

Comment: Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47413094/6314513

Comment: @GowthamSubramaniam  my app working fine in both landscape but not working in file manager open in portrait

Comment: @BipinBharti your error log says that your txtTime  is null. You forget to bind it using findViewById. Check that  once.

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel yes when I choose file after set text in onActivityResult

Comment: @BipinBharti post  your onCreate code with xml layout designs.